# Can a gravitational wave produce oscillating time dilation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, time-dilation

I was reading about gravitational waves and about laser based detectors. I also read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107033/49025). As mentioned in the answer, when ever there is a deformation in spacetime, doesn't it also create a minute time dilation? So in a laser based detector, even if the distance between the objects change when a gravitational wave passes, doesn't the time dilation affect the time taken by the laser to travel between the objects and make it a constant?

Edit

Later I read this [What makes us think we can actually detect gravitational waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25643/what-makes-us-think-we-can-actually-detect-gravitational-waves) as well. But I still think the time dilation argument makes sense.

Answer (score -4):

Here is the metric of the gravitational waves in spherical coordinates ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave#Advanced_mathematics)):

$\eta_{\mu \nu} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 0 & r^2 \sin^2\theta
\end{bmatrix}$

As you can see, it changes only the space coordinates. And only the transversal ones. If there is a change also in the time coordinate, it is not a gravitational wave any more. So, the short answer in the literal sense is a clear *no*.

But, the gravitational waves are coming from the [Einstein Field Eqations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) by calculating the metric far from the accelerating bodies. Somewhere I've read there are other wave-like gravitational effects with different metric, but they decay with higher powers with the distance from the source. Hopefully somebody with a higher understand in the topic will explain its details.

*Extension: Fortunately it already happened in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/41870/32426) wonderful answer.*

Comment: That's the Minkowski metric. The full metric, including $h_{\mu\nu}$ (but not $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}$), does modify time, though by a very small amount.

Comment: @Javier It is about the [Petrov Classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrov_classification)?

Comment: Not at all. It's just that the metric you posted is the flat metric, which doesn't have any gravitational waves in it. Wikipedia tells you $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}$; from that you calculate $h_{\mu\nu} = \bar{h}_{\mu\nu}-\frac12 \bar{h}\eta_{\mu\nu}$, and the full metric is $\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$, which very much does affect time.